# Convert.ToInt32 not accepting string hexadecimal values

Tags: c#

I'm currently making a program which saves a bunch of memory addresses to a class automatically. However,

```
Convert.ToInt32(value)
```

doesn't seem to want to accept the string value "0xB24C" as a valid integer.

> 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Actually I'm able to just save offsets as integers like this `public const Int32 m_ArmorValue = 0xB24C;`

Here's my code where I assign the integer;

```
hazedumper.netvars.m_ArmorValue = Convert.ToInt32(value);
```

value being the string offset `"0xB24C"`

Can anyone tell me why this error is occurring or is it not possible to convert a string memory address/hexadecimal value to an Int32.

Comment: Pretty sure there is some duplicate around, but it is just _var result = Convert.ToInt32(value, 16);_

Comment: @Steve Thanks, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToInt32()` takes the base as second parameter. Furthermore you must remove the `0x` prefix. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-between-hexadecimal-strings-and-numeric-types) for details

```
var s="0xA123";
var i = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(2), 16);
```